# How to read data from serial port on Raspberry Pi+MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, monodevelop

i installed MonoDevelop on raspberry pi.
my send data code is:

```
try
    {

        SerialPort myport = new  SerialPort("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    myport.Open ();

        myport.WriteLine("this is Test");
        myport.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        label1.Text = ex.Message.ToString ();
    }
```

how i can read data from serial port in raspberry pi and mono?
please help me, Thank's

Comment: You might want to consider asking in the RPi group: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/  there are a lot more RPi folks in there

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ReadLine() inbuild method, like this:

```
string buf = myport.ReadLine();
```